# Dynamically not running @Scheduled jobs based on current state of a bean in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduling, spring-scheduled

I'm in the need of runnning/not running a @Scheduled job based on a boolean that's dynamically computed inside of a bean (periodically and also via @Scheduled the bean reads a file and check its content). I've spent a lot time thinking and Googling and haven't come up with a solution until now.

- @ConditionalOn* would not work as that is only read once during initialization
- Subclassing the scheduler doesn't work as the schedule methods are also only called once at startup
- Checking for the property in the scheduled method doesn't work for me as it must not get called at all

Anyone got a clever idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to schedule a convenience method that does the check instead?

Comment: As an addition, I'm using Shedlock to manage scheduling between different instances. I managed to disable the normal Scheduled methods via an AspectJ @Around but am unable to intercept Shedlock's lock gaining execution :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with an Aspect @Around Spring's @Scheduled annotation and then not calling proceedingJoinPoint.proceed():

```
@Around("@annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled)")
```

Handling Shedlock wasn't as 'easy' but I was able to stop the executions with this @Around and then returning Optional.empty() (pretending Shedlock cannot get hold of a lock):

```
@Around("execution(* net.javacrumbs.shedlock.provider.jdbctemplate.JdbcTemplateLockProvider.lock(..)) "
    + "|| execution(* net.javacrumbs.shedlock.core.LockProvider.lock(..))")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start and stop the scheduler programmatically.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.schedule(<runnable>, <interval>);
```

Then you can check for the condition and if it should run schedule (or let it run) or if it shouldn't run you cancel it:

```
scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
```